# not able to get new content using alamofire (not able to refresh the cache content)

Tags: swift, apache, caching, alamofire

for some reason, I'm not able to take advantage of the cache mechanism that alamofire provides and im forced to clear the cache so I can ge the new json content to be parsed by alamofire.

i checked the control header and etag and i printed out the response and request, but i found something weird. check the max-age. my website uses HTTP:

```
request <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7a12b400> { URL: http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts }
response Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a12fd30> { URL: http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Sat, 26 Sep 2015 18:52:14 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    "Last-Modified" = "Sat, 26 Sep 2015 17:43:31 GMT";
    Link = "</wp-json/posts?page=2>; rel=\"next\", 


    Server = Apache;
    **"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";**
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Pingback" = "http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.45";
    "X-WP-Total" = 11;
    "X-WP-TotalPages" = 2;
} })
```

how can I change the max-age and use the reinvalidate control header so that alamofire can know that there is new content on the server and try refresh the cache instead of loading old data?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the response itself, but you can change the second URL request you make to specifically ignore the cache data.

```
let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!)
URLRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

Alamofire.request(URLRequest)
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        print(request)
        print(response)
        print(result)
    }
```